# Is there any way to call a war file that is already deployed on the server from an <a> tag?

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat

I have a war file that needs to be called from a jsp which has an [`<a>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.1.1) tag.
Can this be done?
The war file is already deployed on the server.
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by calling a war file? A resource that is served by the war?

Comment: Web application archive

Comment: My focus was on the "calling" part.

Comment: Sorry. What I need is to run the whole war file on the click of a button. There are two or more war files already deployed on the server. When a button is clicked, one of the war files need to be called. Does that help?

Comment: Do you want to deploy your 'war' on click of another war to the same webserver and not until then?